# How to redirect (301) a bunch of old URLs to new ones?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a bunch of old URLs that need to be redirected (301) to the new ones. I would just write

```
Redirect 301 /old-url http://www.example.net/new-url
```

for every single redirection into the .htaccess. But is there a better solution, maybe using RewriteMap?

Comment: Please provide some urls

Comment: (Is there a|What is the) pattern?

Comment: Old: http://www.example.net/path New: http://www.example.net/path-123

Comment: Old: http://www.example.net/my-first-article New: http://www.example.net/my-first-article-148 Old: http://www.example.net/my-second-article New: http://www.example.net/my-second-article-185 etc. The number is the ID.

Comment: Logic is: old URL + "-ID". My question is, if I should write all lines into .htaccess or is there another/better solution?

Comment: If your logic is to add `ID` at the end, you should do it with PHP since you can have business logic (which you don't have with htaccess and mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

a php redirect will work

more info here www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php
header('location:http://www.yoursite.com/whereve');
?>
```